# How are the routing tables populated on a Debian system?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, iproute2

How are the routing tables populated on a Debian system? I understand that the `ip route` family of commands can be used to manually manipulate the routing tables, but how are the routing tables initially populated on system start, and under what circumstances are the routing tables updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a Debian system, the routing tables are automatically populated whenever network interfaces are brought up or down.  See [`man interfaces`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5), [`man ifup`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ifup&sektion=8), and [`man ip`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ip&sektion=8) for a detailed description.

Essentially, `ifup` reads configuration bits from `/etc/network/interfaces` and then for statically defined interfaces uses `ip route add` to create the appropriate routes.  For interfaces configured to use DHCP, `ifup` requests the configuration bits from the DHCP server and then uses `ip route add` to create those routes as well. When an interface is taken down, `ifdown` deletes the routes that would have been added *based on the current configuration*.  So be aware that when the configuration changes, the routes deleted by `ifdown` might not be the same as the routes originally added by `ifup`.

In `/etc/network/interfaces`, the `pre-up`, `post-up`, `pre-down`, and `post-down` hooks are available to manually manipulate the routing tables (or to run commands for other purposes).

The scripts in `/etc/network/if-*.d/*` provide additional hooks for more complex tasks.